# Auto value post and parse result using beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a python GUI script which shows the meaning of English words to easy Nepali language..I am using sqlite3 as a backend database.. As there are lots of words in english which is really difficult to cover all those in my database, I planned to ask internet for the words to convert if its not on the database.. here is one webpage which I got http://www.englishnepalidictionary.com/, which gives the meaning of particular english words in Nepali language.. but it takes the text value from user and after pressing a button it gives the value just below the text feild.. Now my question is: can a user auto post the text and grab value from that web page using python..? If its possible please bother to suggest me a short syntax how to self attend the text field and button..

Thank you very much in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
query = 'carrot'
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.englishnepalidictionary.com/?q=%s' % query)
soup = bs(page.read())
soup.select('div.search-result h3')[0].text
>>> carrot - गाजर
```

Comment: Wow that was as fast as 2 minutes noodles.. thank you sir.. because of the people like you python community is flourished and we are blessed.. but this code doesn't give any result in my case.. just the program ends without any output..